# Binding Button IsEnabled to StackPanel has Children

Tags: wpf, button, binding, stackpanel, isenabled

I'm wondering if I can bind my Button isEnabled to my StackPanel Children (has children). If the stackpanel has children, then my button is enabled, no children my button is disabled. Currently I just handle this in code, but I started wondering if this was something I could bind. Thanks for any thoughts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually since you deal with a bool you can invert the logic and do it without converters:

```
<StackPanel Name="sp" />
<Button Content="A Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=sp, Path=Children.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Using this you run into some problems in terms of getting updates since `Children.Count` is not a DP, you can use an `ItemsControl` though to get around that (it pretty much behaves like a `StackPanel` by default):

```
<ItemsControl Name="ic" />
<Button Content="A Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ic, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple ValueConverter which does that logic for you. Bind the IsEnabled of the Button to the StackPanel and in your value converter check if it has any children and then return true/false.

Comment: That's probably the simplest way to get it done, though I do wonder if it would update when you added children to a stackpanel?

Comment: First, I would directly bind to the children. However, Children is not a dependency property, so it won't update since there is no notification that something changed :( So you would have to manually trigger the update.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution (requires no `ItemsPanel`) than H.B.'s might be binding to the `ActualHeight` property of the `StackPanel`, since its size will be 0 if no children are present.

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=sp, Path=ActualHeight}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

You may have to use `VerticalAlignment="Top"` for the `StackPanel` if it does not shrink properly.